# Most Windows-like text editor that can be used through PuTTY in NetBSD?

Tags: unix, text-editors, netbsd

Please help me find an editor that behaves more like the modern Windows editors do, that I could use on a NetBSD box through PuTTY.

This includes the absense of the distinction between view/insert/append modes, basic shortcuts such as Ctrl+Left/Right to jump a word at a time, and other niceties such as perhaps Home/End and PageUp/Down moving the cursor around (in my `vi` they just ding).

I can live without macros because I only ever tweak an occasional setting this way, and nothing else.

`pico` is pretty close, but I was wondering if there are other editors that might fit this bill?

Comment: Have you tried easyedit?

Comment: You can try to use editor created for X11 environment (for example gEdit) with ssh X11 forwarding.

Comment: `vi` has never supported such "niceties" as cursor keys. Those were added in `vim`. (When vi was written, terminals didn't _have_ dedicated cursor keys.)

Comment: grawity is so true, vi and vim is not the same thing. Even thou you can make vim behave as vi...

Comment: Agreed, but to some people (incl myself) it's shocking that programs written in the days before cursor keys still survive almost unchanged AND are even made default editors in modern OS releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dit](http://dit-editor.sourceforge.net/). From a [review](http://spiralofhope.wordpress.com/2009/04/26/linux-console-text-editors-almost-all-suck/):

> I can’t contain my glee.  Here are the
>   totally groundbreaking features, never
>   before seen all together in one
>   editor.
>
> - The ability to page up and down.  Revolutionary!
> - Control-left and control-right to hop words.  Amazing!
> - Control-s to save, control-q to quit.  Incredible!
> - Control-c to copy, control-x to cut, control-v to paste.  Astounding!
>
> There’s no sarcasm there at all
>   either.  A usable text editor.

(The author goes on in that post to say "In other news, I decided to implement a DOS editor wrapper using DOSBox.", which shows you where he's coming from, and is sort of awesome.)

---

I tend to use [joe](http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/), though, because I've found it often pre-installed on otherwise-unfamiliar systems, and you can get it on Cygwin. It's not like edit.com, but its little help panel (^KH) makes up for almost all unfamiliarity.

Answer (score 2):

Nano is my editor of choice, as soon as I learned some of the keys (Ctrl+x for close, ctrl+w for find, etc.).

If you have enough bandwidth, X11 forwarding with your editor of choice is a good option. I do this a bit from the windows machine at my work with Xming and PuTTY. Great programs, IMO.

Good luck!

Comment: Nano is a more modern version of Pico

Answer (score 0):

Also found [diakonos](https://github.com/Pistos/diakonos) which seems to be a little more finished than dit.